# ¿COMO PUEDO FILTRAR POR FECHAS QUE MUESTRE LOS DATOS DE ACUERDO AL RANGO?

Tags: php

Si me puede colaborar con la siguiente sintaxis del código lo que sucede estoy realizando un buscador y los estoy haciendo por filtro que consta de una lista donde  me trae los registros que se encuentra en la base de datos, ademas genere 2 input date uno para la fecha  inicial y otro para la fecha final,lo que sucede es que al momento de filtrarlo no me esta trayendo lo que necesito por ejemplo si mi tabla se llama campaña  y tiene una fecha inicial otra una fecha final la idea es que si la fecha  inicial fue creado el 6/10/2018 y la fecha final fue el dia 11/10/2018 la idea es que me muestre los datos de acuerdo a ese rango de fechas en caso contrario si la  fecha  es distinta entonces  no me traiga la informacion, muchas gracias si me pueden colaborar

```
$sql = "SELECT   ca.id_campanas,
ca.nombre,
esc.nombre estado_campanas,
co.nombre convenios,
ca.presupuesto,
ca. fc
   FROM campanas ca . nombre
   INNER JOIN estado_campanas esc ON esc.id_estadoc = ca.id_estadoc
   INNER JOIN convenios co ON co.id_convenios = ca.id_convenios
   WHERE ca.id_campanas = '$bus'
   AND ca.id_convenios = '$id_convenios' 
   AND ca.estado = 'Activo' 
   AND date(`fecha_i`) BETWEEN date('$fechai') AND date('$fechaf')";



$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if($fechai <= $fechaf) {
    echo "</br>";
    echo '<table class="table table-hover">

           <a class="align-middle">
              <thead>
              <tr style="background:#e1e2e6;">
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Nombre de la Campaña</th>
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Nombre Estado de la Campaña</th>
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Nombre del Convenio</th>
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Presupuesto</th>
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Fecha de Creación</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>';

              while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
               {
                 echo "<tr>
                     <td style='text-align: center'>$filas[nombre] </td>
                     <td style='text-align: center'>$filas[estado_campanas]</td>
                     <td style='text-align: center'>$filas[convenios]</td>
                     <td style='text-align: center'>$filas[presupuesto]</td>
                     <td style='text-align: center'>$filas[fc]</td>



                       </tr>";    
               } 

               echo "</table> <br> </div>";

}else  {
    echo "No se encontraron resultados";

}
```

Comment: Tu query tiene el rango de fechas con la misma variable `$fechai`.  Que no deberian de ser dos variables diferentes?

Comment: si  ya lo tiene  esta mi funcion  declarada las variables

Comment: Que no deberia ser: `BETWEEN date('$fechai') AND date('$fechaf')";`

Comment: si ya esta pero en es la condicional si me puede colaborar ya que al momento de realizar la consulta me trae el rango  por ejemplo la fecha de inicio fue de  10/06/2018 y la fecha  final es  el 14/10/2018 me trae el registro pero al cambiarlo me lo trae en blanco o por si ejemplo si yo lo colocara la fecha  inicial 28/10/2018 y  la fecha  final 06/10/2018 muestra no se encontró resultados, pero si colocara  la fecha inicial por ejemplo 1/10/2018 y la fecha final 2/10/2018 me tra en blanco y debería traerme no hay resultados ya que  esta por fuera del rango de fecha que se creo el registro

Comment: Intenta ingresar las fechas con formato `mm/dd/aaaa` en lugar de `dd/mm/aaaa`

Comment: No porque en la base de datos ya viene predeterminado aaaa/mm/ dd

Comment: como lo podía realizar o que condicional lo puedo hacer ya que no me funciona muchas gracias si me puedes colaborar

Comment: agrega un echo $sql para ver como queda finalmente tu query antes de ser ejecutada

Answer (score 0):

Los `/` de tus fechas están causando problemas. Intenta formatear tus variables antes de usarlas en la query, en este caso yo las paso al formato `YYYY-mm-dd`.

Prueba lo siguiente:

```php
$fechai = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$fechai)));
$fechaf = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$fechaf)));

$sql = "SELECT   ca.id_campanas,
ca.nombre,
esc.nombre estado_campanas,
co.nombre convenios,
...
```

Comment: muchas gracias por su colaboración

Comment: hola, como te fue? te sirvió?

Comment: si muchas gracias

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers